# installing tailwindcss v.3.0.15 using PostCSS doesn't work properly

Tags: tailwind-css

I need clarification. I am following the instructions for installation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss.

What I did:

`npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

`npx tailwindcss init` (creates a tailwindcss config file)

What I'm expected to do next:

- Add Tailwind to your PostCSS configuration `postcss.config.js`
- Configure your template paths `tailwind.config.js`

But only `tailwind.config.js` was created automatically. Is this normal and is one expected to create the other file manually? Or does it give a hint that something else is missing?

*** **Edit** ***

I created the `postcss.config.js` manually and added the plugins to it.

And I added the directives to the main.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

however the h1 title

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
```

one is supposed to add to the application to see if everything worked, shows that not everything worked, as "Hello World" is neither bold nor underlined.

*** **Solution** ***
add .jsx to the possible endings

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Did you build the tailwindcss.css file, such as into your app.css file so it can be accessed within the HTML, and did you include it in the HTML? Also can you verify clicking the css file from within the HTML loads up a CSS file?

Comment: Can you share tailwind.config.js

Comment: I am just following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn_Kb3MR_cU) ~ 10:00 - 15:00 (relevant part) using react, vite and tailwindcss, I have no prior experience with this stack.

Comment: Try, In `tailwind.config.js`  `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]` replace to `content: ["*"]`,

Comment: thanks @AnmolMishra you hinted at the right spot. I solved it by adding `.jsx` for the possible file endings

Comment: Below Answer not a copy is right way , I  Changed `tailwind.config.js` file

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @AnmolMishra I missed that, everything else looked the same, so I didn't pay enough attention there. I accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you, Creating manually postcss.config.js file and adding .jsx into tailwind.config.js is fixed my issue too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem where the postcss.config.js file wasn't created for me, to solve it just run `npx tailwindcss init -p` the "-p" part was what created the postcss config file for me.

Comment: solved for me too. but what does the -p flag mean?

Answer (score 1):

I spent whole day to solve this issue. I'm sharing my experience below:

Open your project folder & open `vscode` then open terminal then type command

1. `npm install -D tailwindcss`
2. `npx tailwindcss init`

Then create a **src** Folder with `input.css` file[whatever you can give a name]. Then type code in css file like

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

after that create `index.html` under **src** folder. Then copy paste as tailwindcss doc html code section. Then configure your **tailwind.config.js** content section

```
content: ["./src/index.html"],
```

Now run `npm init -y`
After that need to change **package.json** file like

```
"main": "tailwind.config.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch"
  },
```

Now run command

```
npm run build
```

You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=250R45w2xuQ)

Comment: When running `npm init -y` following your steps it adds: acorn,acorn,binary,acorn,braces,anymatch,arg,browserslist,caniuse,color,chokidar,cssesc,camelcase,detective,defined,didyoumean,electron,dlv,escalade,fast,fill,has,function,is,is,is,is,fastq,fraction,merge2,lilconfig,micromatch,is,minimist,nanoid,node,object,normalize,normalize,path,picocolors,glob,picomatch,pify,postcss,postcss,postcss,postcss,postcss,queue,postcss,quick,read,resolve,reusify,source,readdirp,update,supports,run,util,to,yaml,xtend and more all to my package json

Comment: video link is no longer functional

Comment: Link has been updated. Please Check

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In `tailwind.config.js` you need to add all file extensions that you need to apply Tailwind. For me, I added `jsx` and then it worked perfect.